# Approach for implementing screen in angular (Edit vs view mode ) on click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

We have a similar screen which needs to be developed :

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93159/view-mode-or-always-in-edit-mode

with the following feature :

1. Clicking of button, the fields should be editable.
2. In the image, the data is being repeated, but we have different data ( ex : first card template will be personal information, second one will be addresses, and so on)
3. if there is a change in the  input boxes, then call corresponding API on click of save
   button.

I am confused on how to approach this screen.

1. I was thinking of using forms, where in i can create form controls for individual template and on click of button  push the form in dynamic array. But i am not sure if its the right approach.

Can someone please help me out or point out a similar example which i can reference?

Comment: Do you have ngrx store in your app?

Comment: No but i am using Rxjs behaviour subject

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is about 2 fields :

**UX Design and components organization**

First of all, I think to split correctly your components to do it, atomic design methodology is very good.
In your case, you have a lot of information for each column. So each column need to have a new page to update informations.

**See more : https://medium.muz.li/atomic-design-methodology-166261ce47c2**

But honestly, I'm not a specialist for this part, It's better to post this questions on uxstackexchange.

**Organization and way to manage api calls in Angular app**

**See Atomic design (clean architecture) for Angular here : https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/angular-clean-arquitecture-d40e9c50f51**

I think in your app, the best way to manage data + call api is to implement ngrx store. Because you will have a lot of informations and a lot of call api to manage.

So It's very a good option to implement directly ngrx store to manage this part of your app. And you already use rxjs, so it's the same concept but with a store to manage global state in your entire app.

See more : https://v9.ngrx.io/guide/store

Comment: Thanks. Let me go through the article. 

we won't be able to implement NGRX since the app has certain  limitations.

Comment: The second option is to use Input and Output. And manage call api from components (by services)

Comment: when you say I/O, do you mean the following: 
1. click of save/edit -> emit event  to toggle functionality. 
2. click of save/button -> to emit values  ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because in atomic architecture, normally you can't call api from atoms. They only manage interfaces. So you have to emit event from atoms

Comment: Link to understand and implement atomic design (clean architecture) for Angular added in my answer